pop() inside for loop does not delete all elements of a list
Please clarify why the following code does not remove 3 and 1.
a = [1,3,4,5]
for i in a:
    if a!=[]:
        print(a.pop())
else:
    print('Stack empty')


You're modifying the list you are iterating over. What do you expect to happen? Also, if you stated what the code (seems to be some stack/LIFO operation) is supposed to do, people could perhaps give you a hint how to do it clearly and reliably.

You are trying to modify a list by using "for i in range of original list" while removing items from it, the list obviously becomes smaller than the range and just stops by the third iteration
Do this instead.
a = [1,3,4,5]
while a:
    print(a.pop())
print(a)



When a for loop starts, it creates an iterator over the list. The
iterator keeps track of the index of the elements, and the loop
continues to retrieve elements based on this index, irrespective of
any changes made to the list during iteration.
In contrast, a while loop does not rely on an iterator. Instead, it
re-evaluates the condition at the beginning of each iteration.
 a = [1, 3, 4, 5]
 while a:
     print(a.pop())
 print('Stack empty')



